# How to add files to main repository when using composer?

Tags: php, git, composer-php, git-submodules

In my PHP project I use composer. 
For some reasons (stupid, but it's not depending on me) I must store all project files in a git repository, including "vendor/" files fetched by composer. I've removed "vendor/" from the .gitignore file, but some modules (like https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager) are treated as submodules - 
and they are not being added to the repository (`git add` ignores them).

What do I need to do, to force addition?

Comment: Storing all the vendor files in the repo feels pretty pointless when you're using composer. Why can't you just store the composer.json?

Comment: I know this is stupid but, unfortunately, I am obliged to keep all of the code that allows to run the application in git. This is not my decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following commands:

```
# remove `.git` folders recursively
find vendor -type d -name '.git' -exec rm -rf {} \;
# Add the vendor folder
git add vendor
```

Probably it would be better to persuade your boss that composer isn't meant to work like that.